# Need explanation for the output of the following java code

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iteration

```
public class Test {  
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++);
    System.out.println(i + 4);
  }
}
```

The output of the following code is 14.Why it is not 4?

And how can it be 14? Need some explanation

Thank you in advance...

Comment: The loop sets the variable i to 0. 10 iterations later i is 10. i + 4 is then 14!

Comment: What makes you think the result should be 4?

Comment: You might be confused because of the semicolon at the end of the line, starting with 'for'. That means you defined an empty loop, which increases the variable i ten times. The System.out.println occurs only once after the loop finished, when the value of i is already 10. So the output must be 14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++);
```

This loop does nothing but incrementing `i` by one, 10 times .

Then

```
System.out.println(i + 4);
```

evaluates to

```
System.out.println(10 + 4);

// output
14
```

If you drop the semi colon at the end of `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++);`, you shall get

```
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

as an output.

Answer (score 3):

Simple.

- The loop increments `i` by `10` without doing anything else (notice the `;` after the `for` loop definition)
- The `System.out` statement prints `i + 4` outside the loop (only once), i.e. `14`

Answer (score 0):

See description in comments:

```
        // Declare variable 'i' of type int and initiate it to 0
        // 'i' value at this point 0;
        int i = 0;

        // Take variable 'i' and while it's less then 10 increment it by 1
        // 'i' value after this point 10;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++);

        // Output to console the result of the above computation
        // 'i' value after this point 14;
        System.out.println(i + 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println(i + 4);`  will get evaluated and executed after  `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++);` statement is evaluated.

Result of `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++);` will be `10`. The condition `i < 10` will be true till `i=9` which is the 10th iteration and in the 11th iteration `i` will be `10` as `i++` will be computed and here the `i<10` condition fails. Now final value of `i` will be `10`.
The next statement `System.out.println(i + 4);` is evaluated which is `i(=10)+4 = 14`